# Can I detect opened additional tabs on IPad via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, responsive-design

[image]Right now I am working on responsive app for different devices and I've faced issue - when additional tabs is opened my view is collapsed, when tab is only one (default) it's okay. Is it possible to detect that moment when I have tabs or not? 
Mobile and Desktop view working perfect.

Comment: Tabs? can you add some more details?

Comment: @KarthickManoharan I've added picture

Comment: Strange. Having multiple open tabs should not affect the layout (width) of the webpage. But do you see the increase in height when having multiple tabs?